# Prove that a map $f:S^1\to S^1\times S^1$ is injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $f:S^1\to S^1\times S^1$ be the map defined by:
> $$f(z)=(z^m,z^n)$$
> for some $m,n\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$. I want to prove that $f$ is injective when $gcd(m,n)=1$.

Let $z_1=e^{2\pi t_1i}$ and $z_2=e^{2\pi t_2i}$ such that $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$. Then:
$$(e^{2\pi m t_1i}, e^{2\pi n t_1i})=(e^{2\pi m t_2i}, e^{2\pi n t_2i})$$
is equivalent to:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
m(t_1-t_2)&=\kappa\\
n(t_1-t_2)&=\kappa'
\end{array}\right.$$
From here, how can I show that $t_1=\lambda +t_2$ for some integer $\lambda$ (and thus $f$ is injective)?

Comment: Use Bezout's identity. Also, this is nothing special about $S^1$; it holds for any group $G$.

Comment: precalculus?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **Bezout's Identity**, there exists integer $x,y$ such that $mx+ny=1$.

If $f(z)=f(w)$, then $z^m=w^m, z^n=w^n$.

Then following is valid:

$$z=z^{mx+ny}=(z^m)^x(z^n)^y=(w^m)^x(w^n)^y=w^{mx+ny}=w$$

So $f$ is injection.

Comment: Worth noting this works for any topological group $G$ and function (not a homomorphism in general, but continuous) $G\to G\times G$ defined as $g\mapsto (g^m,g^n).$ It is a group homomorphism if $G$ is abelian.